# How to assemble a list of arguments for a function call

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function like this:

```
def test(*args):
    if 'test1' in args:
        print('Test1')

    if 'test2' in args:
        print('Test2')

    if 'test3' in args:
        print('Test3')
```

And now, my question is: I have some variables (like `a, b, c`), I want to check the variables which is active(or some things) then call my function.

For example: if `a` is `True`, then call `test('test1')`. But if `b` and `c` is `True`, call `test('test2', 'test3')`. If `a` and `c` is `True`. call `test('test1', 'test3')`.

But I don't know how can I do that, I can only do something like this:

```
if a:
    test('test1')
    if b:
        test('test1', 'test2')
        if c:
            test('test1', 'test2', 'test3')

if b:
    test('test2')

and some more code like these.
```

I think there is a easy way to do that.

Comment: And what is the problem in that? What did you try?

Comment: Where you got stuck?

Comment: @AnandSKumar I mean,  is possible to check variables and call function just like I said?

Comment: @AhsanulHaque check the variables are active or not, and call the function like I said.

Comment: Yea , why wouldn't it be? Did you even try that? You should atleast try before you ask questions here.

Comment: @AnandSKumar but I don't know how to do that, let me edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see if this is what you want:

```
a = True
b = True
c = False

args = []

if a: args.append('test1')
if b: args.append('test2')
if c: args.append('test3')

test(*args)
```

Comment: Yes, I want a answer like this. Let me try it. And I'm sorry about that I can not description my question very well.

Comment: It's working. But if only `a` and `c` is `True`. Then it will raise a NameError. And if I use `try`, however the program will not check `c`.

Comment: A NameError only happens if there is no variable with a certain name. Are you sure you have created all variables (and spelled them correctly)?

Comment: I added lines to assign values to a, b and c. Please let me know what would happen if you run the code.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was targeted at @Kevin Guan. This should fix the problem though ;). Additionally I would just drop the `* ` , both in @ycsun's call to `test` and in @Kevin Guan's definition of the `test` function. If you leave it out, `args` will be treated as a list, which supports membership tests using the `in` operator.

Comment: @m00am Hum, however this really fix the problem. And thanks :).

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import takewhile
test(*takewhile(bool, (a, b, c)))
```

Comment: However this answer is more easier. Thanks :)